# How to Convert dates into Quarter in Python Pandas without repeating quarters for preceding 5 years?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-3.6

I want to convert Date into Quarters. I've used,

```
x['quarter'] = x['date'].dt.quarter

        date    quarter
0   2013-1-1          1
```

But, it also repeats the same for the next year.

```
          date    quarter
366   2014-1-1          1
```

**Instead** of the `1`, I want the **(expected result)** quarter to be `5`.

```
          date    quarter
366   2014-1-1          5
.
.
.
.
          date    quarter
731   2015-1-1          9
```

Comment: Actually I'm working on a project to predict values for the future years and I need Quarter as a feature column in my Dataset, Therefore, I want it as 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple mathematical operation

```
starting_year = 2013
df['quarter'] = df.year.dt.quarter + (df.year.dt.year - starting_year)*4

    year        quarter
0   2013-01-01  1
0   2014-01-01  5
0   2015-01-01  9
0   2016-01-01  13
```